# Force on a bar magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

A bar magnet is freely falling vertically inside a conducting ring placed in horizontal plane. Will it fall with an acceleration equal to g, less than g or greater than g?

[image: magnet]

Comment: Hello gpuguy, Welcome to physics.SE. We generally [discourage questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) (from askers) that ask users to solve their own home-made problems. Perhaps, your question is like "choose the best answer" - like that kind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Less than g.</kbd>

Since it generates energy in the conducting ring when passing through the ring, by conservation of energy, the magnet loses some kinetic energy (there are forces acting on the magnet.

<kbd>See [Lenz's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law).</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E97CYWlALEs.
And as Raindrop said, this is predicted by [Lenz's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law).